# SQLite "INDEXED BY" not working in SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, indexing

I have a Tune table which consists of an _id field and an MD5 field.. and other fields which are irrelevant to this question. When I do the following statement I get my MD5 value back:

```
SELECT MD5 FROM Tune WHERE _id='5'
```

I have an index, ITUNEID which I try to use to speed up the locating of a tune record:

```
CREATE INDEX ITUNEID ON Tune (_id)
```

When I use the following statement I get a "No query solution" error.

```
SELECT MD5 FROM Tune INDEXED BY ITUNEID WHERE _id='5'
```

What is wrong with the above statement?

I forgot to mention that _id is the primary key. Is that what the problem is? Is it illegal to specify the usage of an index where the primary key is concerned?

Comment: The posted question aside, why do you feel the need to specify the index here? If it is the primary key, SQLite should automatically pick the right index.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That was my misunderstanding - I didn't realise that it was actually a primary key. I couldnt' understand why INDEXED BY had worked in other places of my code and not for this query. Just trying to optimise the code a bit via the SQL statements.

Comment: The documentation for `INDEXED BY` has this text: "... the named index must be used in order to look up values on the preceding table", could it be that the index has to contain the MD5 column as well?

Comment: There is a difference between a 'normal' primary key and an [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I don't think so. I have used about 10 different indexes (indices?) in my app and they all work fine. Its only this one where I have used the _id which hasn't worked. I'm not an SQL guru BTW :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem - but with additional context. And sadly, still relevant in year 2021.

Error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no query solution` was only raised in Python (in my case 3.8.6 so SQLite 3.32.3) but not in DB Browser for SQLite 3.12.1 (SQLite 3.33.0).

So I checked with newer Python version (3.9.2 - SQLite 3.34.0) and the problem was gone.

I seems that this problem exists only on SQLite below 3.33.0.